# Subdivide Button in Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

In Blender 2.8 i have been unable to find the location of the subdivide button in any menu in edit mode and have only been able to get it using the search key. The lack of any keybind is also making it quite difficult. I am using beta 2.80.41

Comment: You can now right click in *Edit Mode* to open up the *Specials Menu* if that's your question.

Comment: Didn't think to check the right click menu for the subdivide function. Yep it's there thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16):

The *Subdivide operator* can be found:

1. In the *Context menu* aka *Specials menu* (<kbd>RMB</kbd>or <kbd>W</kbd> in case of using 2.7 keymap)

   [image]
2. As part of the *Edge menu* *in Edit Mode*

   [image]
3. Or via <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> by searching for *Subdivide*

   [image]

Comment: The default keymap for Blender 2.80 is Left Click Select, so the "W" shortcut won't work (and will actually do a different thing: changing the selection mode) for a new user using defaults

Comment: @NicolaSap You are right, I am using 2.7 keymap... I have updated the answer.

Comment: Just a note for newcomers: Spacebar is not default for Search – it's F3.

Answer (score 6):

The following info are based on 2.8 and onward. 2.79 and previous versions have it differently.

By default, the fastest way to subdivide between edges selection is Right-Click, followed by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>. Right-Click is now a fully integrated context menu (its content is based on the active menu and the type of selection)
You can see the **Subdivide** in the Context Menu when in Edit Mode with Edge active.

If you don't Right-Click after selecting the edges and then press <kbd>S</kbd> you'll activate the selection scaling mode. If that happen, just right-click to cancel and turn-off the selection scaling mode.

---

### EDIT

If you have the Right-Click set to *Select* (which was the standard in 2.79 or previous), then you won't be able to bring up the menu with that key. In that case, you can press <kbd>W</kbd> to call the **Vertex Context Menu** (*Subdivide* is the first item in this menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can only subdivide once now. To get more than one subdivision you need to use the *Loop Cut* tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ), unless you want to subdivide something like a cone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit Mode*, right click on the object, then select *Subdivide*, after that change *Smoothness* from 0 to 1 and its ready, you have the same function that the older version had.